# Publishing Live Video to CloudFront Streaming

Tags: video-streaming, video-capture, flash-media-server, amazon-cloudfront

I'm doing research into the best way to stream live video in a webapp (multiple user created streams).  So far it looks like using AWS CloudFront to distribute the video to flash clients would be fairly straightforward, but I haven't found much documentation on publishing the video.

Ideally, the publishing interface would be similar to JustinTV or Ustream, in that a simple Flash app would capture the video from a webcam and stream it somewhere.  Does anyone know if this is possible with CloudFront?  If so, does anyone have a link to some documentation or a tutorial?  Amazon's own docs only seem to cover streaming of an already existing video file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, it doesn't look like Cloudfront supports live streaming. From their website:

"Q. Does Amazon CloudFront support live streaming?
Not at this point, but we intend to add this capability in the future. Many customers already use Amazon EC2 to stream live content."

http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/faqs/#Does_Amazon_CloudFront_support_live_streaming

Answer (score 2):

Live Streaming has recently be announced. More information here:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/FeaturedArticles/latest/index.html?LiveStreamingUsingAmazonCloudFront.html